# java, OrbitzWorld consul client - How to manage session and locks?

Tags: java, spring-boot, consul

Using java OrbitzWorld consul client, I am trying to synchronize multiple instances of my java app via `acquireLock` method.

**My code so far:**
Register app as Consul service:

```
private void registerService(Config config) {
        String serviceId = config.getService().getId();
        String serviceName = config.getService().getName();
        long ttl = config.getService().getTtl();
        AgentClient agentClient = client.agentClient();
        Registration service = ImmutableRegistration.builder()
                .id(serviceId)
                .name(serviceName)
                .check(Registration.RegCheck.ttl(ttl))
                .build();
        agentClient.register(service);
        new HeartBeater(agentClient, serviceId, ttl).start();
    }
```

HeartBeater:

```
@Override
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            try {
                client.pass(serviceId);
                Thread.sleep((Math.max(ttl / 2, 1)));
            } catch (NotRegisteredException | InterruptedException e) {}
        }
    }
```

The code above works and service successfully refreshes in the consul.
Now I wonder about the implementation of locking.

What I have written so far:

```
public boolean amILeader() {
    // return if current java app is leader
}

private String createSession() {
    final Session session = ImmutableSession.builder().name(config.getService().getName()).build();
    return client.sessionClient().createSession(session).getId();
}

private void watchLeaderLockStateChange() {
    KeyValueClient keyValueClient = client.keyValueClient();
    KVCache kvCache = KVCache.newCache(keyValueClient, Constants.LEADER_LOCK_KEY, config.getService().getWatchKey());
    kvCache.addListener(map -> {
        Value value = map.get(Constants.LEADER_LOCK_KEY);
        if(!value.getSession().isPresent()) {
            keyValueClient.acquireLock(Constants.LEADER_LOCK_KEY, ???); //create new session here ???
        }
    });
    kvCache.start();
}
```

I am stuck here as I don't understand the theory and haven't found anything useful in the documentation.

My questions:

- is the session necessary for synchronizing via `acquireLock` method ?
- if so, when and how should the session be created/synchronized over?
- is session invalidation a common thing? According to documentation it happens if one of the services fails to send ttl, which can be very often.
- how do the living services synchronize about creating a new session?
- how do the services synchronize over lock?

Can you provide some code samples or fill in my implementation?
Thanks for any response :]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I get it now.

The theory is like this:

- Consul session represents a connection from a single service to Consul. In my case, it represents a connection between one of my java app instances and Consul
- the session is used to acquire the lock. As the client comes to Consul and wants to acquire the lock, Consul will check if there is any sessionId associated with it. If there isn't, Consul gives a lock to the client and associates clients sessionId with the lock.
- the lock is nothing fancy. It's just a key in KV map saved on Consul node.
- you can check the lock and if any sessionId is associated with it like so:

```
    public class SessionFacade {
        private String leaderLock;
        private String sessionId;
        private Consul client;
        private Config config;

        public SessionFacade(Consul client, Config config) {
            this.client = client;
            this.config = config;
            this.leaderLock = "service/" + config.getService().getName() + "/leader";
            this.sessionId = createSession();
            new SessionHeartBeater(client, sessionId, config.getService().getSessionTtl()).start();
            watchLeaderLockStateChange(sessionId);
            client.keyValueClient().acquireLock(leaderLock, sessionId);
        }

        public boolean doIPossesLeaderLock() {
            Optional<Value> leaderValue = client.keyValueClient().getValue(leaderLock);
            if(leaderValue.isPresent()) {
                Optional<String> session = leaderValue.get().getSession();
                return session.isPresent() && session.get().equals(sessionId);
            }
            return false;
        }

        private String createSession() {
            int sessionTtl = config.getService().getSessionTtl();
            final Session session = ImmutableSession.builder()
                    .name(config.getService().getName())
                    .ttl(sessionTtl + "s")
                    .build();
            return client.sessionClient().createSession(session).getId();
        }

        private void watchLeaderLockStateChange(String sessionId) {
            KeyValueClient keyValueClient = client.keyValueClient();
            KVCache kvCache = KVCache.newCache(keyValueClient, leaderLock, config.getService().getWatchLockEach());
            kvCache.addListener(map -> {
                Value value = map.get(leaderLock);
                if(!value.getSession().isPresent()) {
                    keyValueClient.acquireLock(leaderLock, sessionId);
                }
            });
            kvCache.start();
        }
    }
```

Note that the code is probably buggy as I havent tested it fully yet.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read through https://learn.hashicorp.com/consul/developer-configuration/elections yet?  It walks through this scenario at the level of an app using Consul for leader elections.

Comment: Yes, I have. But as it is an only one-way example via REST, it's not much of use. While it presents some of the possibilities and how to do some things, I miss both high-level theory and low-level implementation.